# Bottom Overflowed by 81 Pixels

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm pretty much self-tutoring flutter and I'm working on a personal project. I wrapped it to singlechildscrollview but it still produces the problem. The code below:

```
class ScheduleDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  var data;
  ScheduleDetail(this.data);
  @override
  // ScheduleDetail({Key key, this.todos}) : super(key: key);
  _ScheduleDetailState createState() => _ScheduleDetailState();
}

class _ScheduleDetailState extends State<ScheduleDetail>{
  String foos = 'One';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.instance =
        ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1425, allowFontScaling: true)
          ..init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          // title:  Text("String Master"),
          title: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/Logo_small.svg'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: BackgroundImageWidget(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(150),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(40),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      AppStrings.scheduleTitle,
                      style: TextStyles.appName,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(50),
                  ),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.82),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(40),
                                ),
                                child: new Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    _buildTopCard(),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    _buildTimeCard(),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text(
                                        "Calendar",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.green,
                                            fontSize: 16
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 1),
                                    _buildNoticeExpansionTile(),
                                    Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 1),
                                    _buildMemoExpansionTile(),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    )
                  ),
            ],
          )),
        )));
  }

  Widget _buildTopCard() {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
      ),
      elevation: 15,
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0))),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 30)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.data['eventTitle'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        widget.data['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade600
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                      child:
                        Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: Row (
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              widget.data['startDate'] + " " + widget.data['timeStart'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  fontSize: 14
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(flex: 2),
                            Text(
                              widget.data['startDate'] + " " + widget.data['timeEnd'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            ),
            Positioned(
                left: 10,
                top: 7,
                width: 325,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Row (
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        widget.data['startDate'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      Spacer(flex: 2),
                      Text(
                        widget.data['timeStart'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTimeCard() {
    return Container(
      height: 125,
      width: 400,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.green,
          width: 0.5,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'TIME OF EVENT',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNoticeExpansionTile() {
    return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white, accentColor: Colors.white),
        child: ExpansionTile(
            title: new Text(
              "Notice",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontSize: 16
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: widget.data['notice'] != null ? widget.data['notice'].length : 0,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "\u2022 " + widget.data['notice'][index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14
                          ),
                        )
                      );
                    }
                )
              ),
            ]
        )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMemoExpansionTile() {
    return
      Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white, accentColor: Colors.white),
          child: ExpansionTile(
              title: new Text(
                "Memo",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontSize: 16
                ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: widget.data['memo'] != null ? widget.data['memo'].length : 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            (index + 1).toString() + ". " + widget.data['memo'][index],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14
                            ),
                          )
                      );
                  }
                )
              ]
          )
      );
  }
}
```

Perhaps my mistake could be from one of those objects that I have used. However, I can't figure it out even though I searched around the internet. My intention is when the expandable tiles have 'overlapped' the screen size, you would be able to scroll it all the way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the scaffold then wrapped SingleChildScrollView within Flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` in `Expanded` Widget.

You can make use of the flutter dev tools for identifying overlapping issues.

Comment: I see. After trying the expanded, it still occurs. However, I think this devtools gonna help me a lot.